# Sequentially assign values from two different lists to a column in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, list, iteration, sequence, multiple-columns

I have two different values (animal or tool) in the column of the dataframe. So each cell is either animal or tool. I have a separate animal names list and a tool names list (that have the actual names of tools and animals). I want my code to iterate through each cell of the column in dataframe and assign an animal name from the animal list if the cell value = animal; or tool name from the tool list if the cell value is tool. I want this to be done sequentially so if the dataframe looks like:

```
Index  Category
0      animal
1      animal
2       tool
3      animal
4       tool
```

and the animal list is:

```
cat
dog
parrot
bird
cheetah
```

and tool list is:

```
nail
iron
hammer
wheel
screw
```

the output should be:

```
Index Category    Output
0      animal     cat
1      animal     dog
2       tool      nail
3      animal     parrot
4       tool      iron
```

It seems like this should be fairly straightforward in Python but haven't been successful. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since there are only two categories, `animal` and `tool`, you can approach this problem in a simple and efficient way by selecting the rows that contain the former and the latter category value separately and assigning the lists to them:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category": ['animal', 'animal', 'tool', 'animal', 'tool'], "Output": np.nan})
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'parrot', 'bird', 'cheetah']
tool_list = ['nail', 'iron', 'hammer', 'wheel', 'screw']

# solution
df.loc[df.Category == 'animal', 'Output'] =  np.resize(animal_list, df.loc[df.Category == 'animal', 'Output'].shape)
df.loc[df.Category == 'tool', 'Output'] =  np.resize(tool_list, df.loc[df.Category == 'tool', 'Output'].shape)
```

Comment: This doesn't have the same output as the OP specified.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to mislead anyone. I've got a fever so I couldn't think clear enough.

Comment: No worries; I make these kinds of mistakes when answering on SO all the time. Looks good now.

Comment: @Arn Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally assign the values using two `.loc` calls. Additionally I specify how many values to take from each list using two `.len` calls.

```
df.loc[df['Category'] == 'animal','Output'] = animal[:len(df[df['Category'] == 'animal'])]
df.loc[df['Category'] == 'tool','Output'] = tool[:len(df[df['Category'] == 'tool'])]
```